# Just a simple riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> You can see me running but no legs can be seen.
>   I like to return to places I've just been.
>   Sometimes I get all angry and mad.
>   So I love to wrap up warm with my dad.
>   Often I'll just jump left and right.
>   But I'm clumsy and fall down from a height.

What am I?

A side note that may be confusing some people:

> The "wrap up warm" part of the line is much more important than the "dad" part of the line.

**HINT/NOTE ONE**

> Each line of the riddle is a clue to a different word, and each word is a type of what I am.

**HINT TWO**

> @Astralbee is very close

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you:

> A *sewing stitch*? Specifically different kinds of stitch....

You can see me running but no legs can be seen.

> A needle can perform a *running stitch*

I like to return to places I've just been.

> A *backstitch* is where the needle comes back down into the same hole at the end of the last stitch you made.

Sometimes I get all angry and mad.

> a *cross-stitch* ("cross" can mean mad!)

So I love to wrap up warm with my dad.

> a *wrap stitch* is for knitting with wool - wool is warm.

Often I'll just jump left and right.

> A *zig-zag* stitch

But I'm clumsy and fall down from a height.

> a *drop* stitch ("drop" as in fall)

Comment: You're oh so very close. The first line is correct but the rest and the answer are not. Have a look at the hints and give it another go! :D +1

Comment: Could also be something like rot13(erpbeq cynlre arrqyr)

Comment: @AHKieran How about now?

Comment: I was thinking a rot13(oynaxrg fgvgpu naq fyvc fgvgpu vafgrnq bs jenc naq qebc) but you're close enough that I'm gunna give it to you, well done!

Comment: @AHKieran Whats rot13(oynaxrg fgvgpu naq fyvc fgvgpu vafgrnq bs jenc naq qebc)? Im pretty curious about that now

Comment: @MasterYoda Caesar cipher with key=13. It's a pity this site doesn't have in-comment spoilers though.

Comment: @MasterYoda i use this chrome extension to decypher them https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rot13/bahejodllcomogcpgnidcdaiidfmhomh

Comment: Ah I see :) thanks guys. I guess it works lol

Answer (score 11):

Are you

> Water?

You can see me running but no legs can be seen.

> As in, running water.

I like to return to places I've just seen.

> The water cycle means that water returns to lakes and oceans eventually

Sometimes I get all angry and mad.

> Thunderstorms? Waterfalls? Hurricanes?

So I love to wrap up warm with my dad.

> Could this be the Sun?

Often I'll just jump left and right.

> A meandering river or a river flowing down a mountain.

But I'm clumsy and fall down from a height.

> A waterfall (or rain).

Comment: Nice guess but that's not what I am +1 tho :D

Answer (score 6):

You are a

> clock

You can see me running but no legs can be seen.

> hourglass

I like to return to places I've just been.

> analog watch

Sometimes I get all angry and mad.

> Cuckoo clock

So I love to wrap up warm with my dad. - only one I am really unsure about?

> one of those wind up clocks? Father time?

Often I'll just jump left and right.

> pendulum clock

But I'm clumsy and fall down from a height.

> Cuckoo clocks that uses weights to wind

Comment: Again this is a nice answer but not correct. Read the hints/notes and have another go :) +1

Answer (score 6):

Are you a

> Stitch

You can see me running but no legs can be seen.

> Running stitch

I like to return to places I've just been.

> Back stitch

Sometimes I get all angry and mad.

> Cross stitch

So I love to wrap up warm with my dad.

> Blanket stitch

Often I'll just jump left and right.

> Zigzag stitch

But I'm clumsy and fall down from a height.

> Slip stitch

Comment: Yes that's completely correct but I'm afraid you were beaten to the finish line by Astralbee.  Well done though!

Comment: Giving you a +1 and kudos for getting the two that I deviated on slightly.

Comment: @Astralbee I wouldn't have gotten it without reading your needle guess first!

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Slinky?

You can see me running but no legs can be seen.

> No legs, but it does motorvate.

I like to return to places I've just seen.

> We bring it up the stairs, and it walks back down.

Sometimes I get all angry and mad.

> The Red Slinky:[image]

So I love to wrap up warm with my dad.

> [image]

Often I'll just jump left and right.

> [image]

But I'm clumsy and fall down from a height.

> Down the stairs.

Comment: This is a very good answer but alas not the one I'm looking for. +1 though

Comment: gotta love those crazy answers in here!!

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Stream/River?

You can see me running but no legs can be seen.

> Running water or the flow of the stream/river

I like to return to places I've just been.

> The stream/river flows continuously to each and every places it has already been

Sometimes I get all angry and mad.

> The harsh currents of the stream/river

So I love to wrap up warm with my dad.

> I think this refers to the mighty ocean

Often I'll just jump left and right.

> This refers to the direction of the stream/river

But I'm clumsy and fall down from a height.

> Refers to the waterfalls

Comment: El-Guest gave a similar answer but it's wrong. Have a look at the hints! :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you,

> Electric?

I'm currently so busy to elaborate for each line but I'll try to explain why I answered with this.

Comment: Sorry but no, I am not :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Rain?

You can see me running but no legs can be seen.

> Rain is water, it can run but has no legs

I like to return to places I've just been.

> Rain often falls in one location then returns multiple times throughout the day/week/year.

Sometimes I get all angry and mad.

> Storms cause rain to fall violently

So I love to wrap up warm with my dad.

> Not sure about this, are you referring to clouds as the dad?

Often I'll just jump left and right.

> When rain hits the ground it splashes in all directions.

But I'm clumsy and fall down from a height.

> Rain falls from the sky, or more specifically the clouds that carry water condensation.

Comment: El-Guest gave a similar answer but I'm afraid it is wrong. Have a look at the hints :)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the response. Good puzzle :) I would have never guessed the answer.